# Is dusk is mandatory to write phpunit test cases?how to write phpunit test cases in laravel 5.4?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk, laravel-testing

I am newbie to laravel. I am using laravel 5.4 version, we have requirement of writing phpunit test cases for our application, So I have searched for writing phpunit testcases and also read the documentation in laravel website. I read about the 'dusk' feature for doing the browser tests. So, I have a doubt that is "Is the dusk is mandatory for writing the phpunit test cases in laravel 5.4? I also tried to install the 'dusk' package into our application but it is not getting installed after I run the command "composer require laravel/dusk".

below is the error that I am getting on command prompt:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\ourappname>composer require laravel/dusk
using version ^1.1 for laravel/dusk
./composer.json has been updated 
Loading composer repositories with package information 
Updating dependies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 4 updates, 9 removals
- Removing maatwebsite/excel (2.1.17)
- Removing phpoffice/phpexcel (1.8.1) 
- Removing jeremeamia/superclosure (2.3.0)
- Removing symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.3.0)
- Removing symfony/polyfill-util (v1.3.0)
- Removing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.2.3)
- Removing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.4.2)
- Removing psr/http-message (1.0.1)
- Removing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1)
- Updating psy/psysh (v0.8.3 => v0.8.5): Loading from cache
- Updating swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.7 => v5.4.8): Loading from cache
- Updating sebastian/diff (1.4.1 => 1.4.2): Loading from cache
- Updating laravel/framework (v5.4.21 => v5.4.23): Loading from cache
- Installing facebook/webdriver (1.4.1): Loading from cache
- Installing laravel/dusk (v1.1.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize


[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' not found

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
c:\xampp\htdocs\ourappname>
```

Anyone please tell me how to fix it? and also what is the process for writing the test cases in laravel 5.4? should we use 'dusk'? or any other way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, Dusk is not required to do unit testing. You can just use the [basic tests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/testing).

Your error is related to when you installed the Excel package on your application; the Service Provider was added to your config/app.php, but now that you've removed the package from your application ("Removing maatwebsite/excel (2.1.17)") you also need to remove the Service Provider.